# oprofile unable to produce call graph

Tags: performance, profiling, g++, oprofile

I am trying to use oprofile to generate call graph.
Compiler is g++, platform is linux x86-64, linker is gfortran

C++ code is compiled with -fno- omit-frame-pointer.
oprofile is started with --callgraph=25.
report I run with --callgraph.

the call graph is produced but it's only includes self time, which is not much use

what am I missing?

Comment: Are you passing `-g` to the compiler ?

Comment: @Paul yes, linker and compiler get -g.  I can produce annotated code as well

Comment: FWIW: here's my viewpoint that the call graph is perhaps not what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Answer (score 2):

Check if `opcontrol --status` does not have

```
Call-graph depth: 0
```

in its output. If it does, stop profiling, do `opcontrol --callgraph=<desired call stack depth>`, and restart profiling.