# oprofile unable to produce callgraph on ARM

Tags: profiling, g++, performance, oprofile

This is actually an exact duplicate of [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907066/oprofile-unable-to-produce-call-graph) question which unfortunately does not have any answer. Is it possible to get a proper callgraph on ARM? I'm using oprofile 0.9.6 on an ARM926 which does not have performance counters so oprofile defaults to using the timer interrupt, I've set the --callgraph option and my app is compiled with the proper flags. 
I'm not trying to profile the kernel but I was wondering if I have to compile also the kernel 
with "framepointer" enabled in order to get a proper callgraph from my app.

Thanks

Comment: If you're looking to make your code go as fast as possible, call graphs are missing the point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343  What you need is wall-time stack samples, summarized by percent at the line level in your code, not the kernel.

Comment: Very interesting alternatives, but unfortunately I'm stuck with oprofile and callgraphs/annotations.

Comment: Hey, I'm not big into ARMs. Is there really no debugger for them that you can pause or manually interrupt? I used to use in-circuit-emulators (ICE) to do this. You may be stuck with callgraphs, in which case the problems will be much harder to find.

Comment: Can you list your main function please?